# Node js server not receiving data from angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a data at angularjs client. when i send the data to server using $http.post, i am not able to read data at server. I dont understand where i have gone wrong ?
This is the angular code:

```
var data = $.param({
        id:$scope.user_id,
  });
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
$http.post('/getdetails',data)
```

Here is the node js server code:

```
app.post('/getdetails',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.body.id);

});
```

output at server log:

```
{}
undefined
```

I am not concerned about data i send, i am only concerned whether it is readable at server or not.

Thanks !

Comment: Using [express](http://expressjs.com)? You'll need to use a [body-parsing middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body).

Comment: What is status doing there? You need to handle the status in the failure block

Comment: Yes, I am using body-parser

Comment: What is the displayed value of `JSON.stringify(data)` before the post is sent?

Comment: "id:1" -- user_id is the number input box in my html

Comment: Why the minus vote ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to serialise your data using $.param() which is used only in the GET method and not in post. Just send your JSON data directly to nodeJs like this :

```
var data = {
        id:$scope.user_id,
  };
$http.post('/getdetails',data)
```

In you headers specify :

```
"Content-Type" : "application/json"
```

So the final request will be like this :

```
$http.post('/getdetails',data,{headers : {"Content-Type" : "application/json"}})
```

Comment: Well, I tried it and it seems to not work !!! Same results prevail. "app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));" Is this correct way to include bodyparser ??

Comment: yes also add these :app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

Comment: That way it will handle all these types based on the header sent in the request